# Does the Canon MF Scan Utility Support scanning multiple pages into individual files?

Tags: printer, multi-function-printer, document-scanning

I have a stack of invoices that I would like to scan into individual files so I can send to different people. Is there any way to do that on through the MF Scan app? Or if not, any other options?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [online manual](https://oip.manual.canon/USRMA-1480-zz-DR-enUV/contents/dwu-scan.html), there does not seem to be a way to do it with Canon's utility.

I use Irfanview ([free download](https://www.irfanview.com/main_download_engl.htm)) for batch scanning. You give it a base file name, and each scan gets that name with an incremental number. With an ADF you just load the documents and press Scan; without ADF, you press Scan for each document.

If you use it, I suggest a donation, because it's a brilliant package that does a lot more than you expect.